# Lost commits in git

Tags: git, github

Our remote git repository (on github) is showing '... authored 3 months ago', even though commits were made a few days ago.

Someone must have accidentally run a hard reset. Is there any way to find out the user who performed this operation?

Comment: Have you tried going through the [reflog](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) in your local repo? You might be able to recover the commit your branch used to point to, reset the branch to it, and push.

Comment: reflog will only show what happened from @Osiris computer.

Comment: reflog is purely local. Nothing incriminating in my local repo. 
@Jubobs This happened on master. We've remerged from the dev branch, and all is fine now. Just wanted to know how this happened.

Comment: @Osiris Nevermind the reflog. Good to know that everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com), you could figure out who made the blunder, because it allows you to [audit repository events](https://enterprise.github.com/help/articles/audit-logging#repository-events), including force push events:

> In addition to the repository events mentioned above, every push to a
>   repository is logged with the following information:
>
> - who performed the push
> - whether it was a force push or not
> - which branch was pushed to
> - which protocol was used
> - the originating IP address
> - which Git client was used

However, I don't think you can get access to such an audit trail with a free GitHub account.

Comment: It's an enterprise account - waiting for a response from the local github guys. Thanks!